# Fluent NHibernate: Eager load multiple collections in mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

Given I have the following entity with multiple collection properties...

```
public class Parent 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set;}  
    public virtual ICollection<FirstChild> FirstChildren { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SecondChild> SecondChildren { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way I can simultaneously eager load both of these properties using fluent NHibernate? Or simply eager load everything associated to the Parent.

If I have the following as my mapping...

```
public ParentMapping()
{
    Id(p => p.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

    HasMany(p => p.FirstChildren)
        .Table("FirstChildren")
        .KeyColumn("Id")
        .Inverse()
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
        .Fetch.Join();

    HasMany(p => p.SecondChildren)
        .Table("SecondChildren")
        .KeyColumn("Id")
        .Inverse()
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
        .Fetch.Join();
}
```

The mapping above results in the error:

> 'Cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags'.

Using the Fetch.Join() in the mapping works if I use it on just one of the properties.

I am able to eager load everything by using `ToFuture()` queries, however, I would prefer to do this in the mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ISet` instead of `ICollection` to use that feature.

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5865605/1486443) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30924319/1486443).

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without using ISet? As if I use Fetch.Join() on one of the collection properties it works fine. Its just when using it on multiple properties that the issue occurs.